# Eigen `sum()` function gives different for same vector in two versions of program

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I am using Eigen c++ library for linear algebra operations.

There is a variable `v` in my code that is a `VectorXd` type, and I need to calculate its sum, so I called `v.sum()`.

However, when I updated my program to a new version, although the value of `v` remain same(read from the same input file), the `sum()` function give slightly 
different value.

Here is a piece of code that explains my problem:

```
double vsum1 = v.sum();
double vsum2 = 0; // compare with manually calculated sum
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    vsum2 += v(i);
}
cout << "sum1: " << vsum1 << endl;
cout << "sum2: " << vsum2 << endl;
```

for the old version, the result is

```
sum1: 94.8117866666666487
sum2: 94.8117866666666202
```

for the new version , the result is

```
sum1: 94.8117866666666345
sum2: 94.8117866666666202
```

The manually calculated sum `vsum2` remains unchanged, so I think the origin vector `v` didn't change, then why would `sum()` give different result? Is it because of 
some SIMD optimization performed by Eigen?

The difference is actually neligible, but that leads to a failure of regression test.

Comment: Old and new versions both run on same machine? I assume, yes.

Comment: Yes, and compiled with same Eigen

Comment: Yes, it's likely that vectorization or other optimizations are responsible for this. Optimizing floating-point operations usually means scarifying bit-for-bit reproducibility. If possible, change your tests to allow for some reasonable tolerance.

Comment: Was browsing recent commits in the Eigen repository but was not lucky finding any suspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5gon12eder's comment is right. Eigen3.3 perform AVX vctorization if available (4 double at once) compared to SSE only in Eigen3.2 (2 double at once). In any case, you must use some tolerance when comparing floating-point numbers to account for round-off errors. You can take inspiration from Eigen's unit tests.